# Possible Nullpointer in spring-kafka

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

we are using **spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE** and get this error in production:

> exception java.lang.NullPointerException
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null at
>   org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.access$000(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:271)
>   ~[spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.getAssignedPartitions(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:152)
>   ~[spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE] at

we are using following props:

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, host);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, autoCommit);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimeout);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, EspDLPResponseDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, reconnectMs); // when esp server unreachable, default value too small
props.put(ConsumerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, retryBackoff); // default value too small
props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRec);

if (saslEnabled) {
props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, "PLAIN");
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SASL_SSL");
// jaas.conf with -D server start parameter
props.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, jaas_config);
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, ssl_keystore);
}
```

Can you please check?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bug. We indeed doesn't check there if `this.listenerConsumer != null`. This property is populated from the `doStart()`, but there is no guarantee that `getAssignedPartitions()` won't be called before that. For example I see its usage in the `toString()`:

```
public String toString() {
        return "KafkaMessageListenerContainer [id=" + getBeanName()
                + (this.clientIdSuffix != null ? ", clientIndex=" + this.clientIdSuffix : "")
                + ", topicPartitions=" + getAssignedPartitions()
                + "]";
    }
```

Please, raise a GH issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues

As a workaround don't beans creating.

Comment: The issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/522. Time to accept the answer: nothing more to explain!